# Shouldn't Zipper still be a werewolf (dog)?

Tags: plot-explanation, cursed

In the movie [Cursed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0257516/), they explain how: if you get bitten by a werewolf, you'll turn into one and to become human again, you'll have to kill that werewolf who bit you.

Jimmy got bitten by Jake so Jimmy has to kill Jake.
But during the movie just after Jimmy got bitten, his dog Zipper bites Jimmy and gets the werewolf blood in him and so he's a werewolf-dog and technically he has to kill Jimmy to turn into a normal dog right?

Eventually Jimmy kills Jake an turns human again but what about Zipper? Is he still a werewolf-Dog? He should still be right?

Comment: *"He should still be right?"* - Why should he, *Jimmy* isn't anymore anyway. If anything, you shouldn't take that quote too literally. He either would have to kill *Jimmy* or just turn him back into a human, I guess.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Jimmy isn't anymore because Jake made him a werewolf and he killed Jake. Skipper should still be a Werewolf(-dog)( since skipper is a dog) because Jimmy infected him and NOT Jake? Right or by killing Jake all of the 'werewolf bloodline' gets turned back into humans/normaldogs even if a sub-sub werewolf infected somebody else?

Comment: According to the movie's dialogue if interpreted strictly, it's the former, according to what the movie shows us it's apparently the latter. Or was there a scene in the movie which hinted at the dog still being a werewolf, I don't remember?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson There wasn't any scene at the ending which indicates that Skipper still is a werewolfdog or not hence the question ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Jimmy  and his sister Ellie were both bitten/scratched by Joanie, NOT Jake**. This attack happened in the first 20 minutes of the movie when Jimmy and Ellie were involved in a car accident with Becky who was Joanie's intended [victim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursed_(2005_film)).

> On that same night, teenager Jimmy Myers is picked up on Hollywood
>   Blvd by his sister Ellie, who just came back from visiting her
>   boyfriend Jake Taylor. Jimmy had a run in with some bullies and his
>   crush Brooke. On their way home, Jimmy and Ellie hit an animal and
>   another car. They attempt to rescue the other driver, Becky Morton,
>   but she is suddenly dragged and ripped in half by an unseen creature.
>   **Jimmy and Ellie are both slashed by the creature's claws, but make it
>   out alive.**
>   In the meantime she figures out that Jake is a werewolf. He confirms
>   it, but **claims it wasn't him that attacked her and Jimmy. Another
>   werewolf attacks, seemingly proving his story.**

2. **The dog's name is "[Zipper](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1828826/?ref_=tt_cl_t6)" NOT "Skipper".**

The only reference to Jake biting or scratching someone and turning them into a werewolf was when he accidentally turned Joanie during a night of rough sex.

Zipper was turned into a werewolf-dog from biting Jimmy.

Remember that after Joanie is killed, Jimmy and Ellie are still infected with the curse.  This is because Jake turned Joanie into a werewolf.  The original curse has to be lifted, meaning it did not matter if Joanie was killed, if the werewolf that killed Joanie was still alive, the curse is still in effect.

Even though Jake did not directly turn anyone in the movie besides Joanie, he is the main source for the curse.

**The curse was not lifted on everyone until Jake died. (including Zipper)**